# Python Darts API

Tags: python, deep-learning, time-series

I'm using the darts API for some time series prediction in python, while looking at the documentation for the [RNN model](https://unit8co.github.io/darts/generated_api/darts.models.forecasting.rnn_model.html) I saw this parameters called training length. The description is not very clear how it is used internally by the model.

As an example, say I have a time series with 20 time steps, and I build a RNN model with the training length equal to 12, does that mean that only the first 12 timesteps will be used in training?